# Why are chunked responses not entirely served?

Tags: scala, iframe, playframework, playframework-2.2, future

Hello fellow Play/Scala developers. I don't know if a question like this belongs here or on some sort of other network-oriented Q/A, but here it goes:

I have a Play app that serves search results by calling another service using multiple requests. The responses to the different requests are sent as chunks. Basically the requests are all fired and as soon as a request is finished, the result is sent back using Comet: I use the iframe method described by [Play's doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaStream).

However, I noticed that in some cases, the iframe call finishes before all data has been sent back to the end user. I debugged a little and found that the requests eventually all finish and my browser shows a net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING. I also noticed that the amount of data transferred to UI varies from one browser to the another.

Here is how my result looks:

```
Ok.chunked(
      (stringEnumerator1 &> Comet(callback = "script1")) >- 
      (stringEnumerator2 &> Comet(callback = "script2")) >- 
      (stringEnumerator3 &> Comet(callback = "script3")) 
).as(HTML)
```

As far as what I've read in [Play's doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaStream), this should do the trick but it doesn't and I have no idea how to solve this. Does anyone have a slight idea or tip on this?

**EDIT**

Here is how the enumerators are created. Once the call to the distant server has been emitted, I get a `Future` of an `Option` of the `case class` I'm expecting from one particular call. This future is passed to a method that calls a method (`toHTML`) on the given `case class`, this method creates an `HTML Elem` that is basically appended to a given `div` once a callback is called on the client's side. `Part` is an abstract class that my case classes inherit from then implement the `toHTML` method.

Here is the method that transforms a given part into an `HTML` string:

```
def getEnumerator[X <: Part](part: Future[Option[X]]): Enumerator[String] = 
    Enumerator.flatten(part.map(Enumerator(_))).map(xopt => xopt.map(x => x.toHTML.toString).getOrElse(PartNotFound().toHTML.toString))
```

**EDIT 2**

I found where the issue was, the thing is that in my `HTML` generation, there was a sum of two integers, one of these integers was at some point `null`, which made the `HTML` generation fail, Play then dropped the connection, what bugs me is that Play didn't throw an exception when that sum occurred.

Comment: AFAIK Enumerator should end with `EOF`. Can you check if you get it?

Comment: I tried adding the `.addThen(Enumerator.eof)` to my existing Enumerator but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I would guess that one of your `stringEnumerator`s isn't completing. Try replacing them with `Enumerator("dummy data here")` and see what behavior you get. Also, could you post the code for one of these `Enumerator`s?

Comment: @wingedsubmariner, please refer to my edit for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "incomplete chunked encoding" error occurs because a `Future` used to build your `Enumerator` is completing as a failure.

HTTP has no way to communicate that an error has occurred during the process of sending a response, not even with chunked responses. When you give Play's `Ok.chunked` an `Enumerator` that fails, it has two choices for how to respond:

1. Deliver the final empty chunk to complete the request. This is dishonest, and nothing on the front-end will be able to tell that an error has occurred.
2. Drop the connection.

Play chooses option 2, which is what is causing the "incomplete chunked encoding" error.

The way to fix this is to ensure, as far as possible, that your `Enumerator` will not fail. Here is a replacement for your `getEnumerator` method that deals with a failed `Future`:

```
def getEnumerator[X <: Part](part: Future[Option[X]]): Enumerator[String] =
  Enumerator.flatten {
    part recover {
      case _ => Some(ErrorGettingPart)
    } map { x =>
      Enumerator(x.getOrElse(PartNotFound).toHTML.toString)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Actually, I found the issue, the thing is that in my HTML generation, there was a sum of two integers, one of these integers was at some point null, which made the HTML generation fail, and as you said, Play dropped the connection, what bugs me is that Play didn't throw an exception when that sum occured.